# When trying to deploy a smart contract, I keep getting `Error HH100: Network ropsten doesn't exist` -- how do I resolve?

Tags: ropsten, hardhat, rinkeby, alchemy

I'm running through [these docs](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/how-to-write-and-deploy-an-nft/) on deploying an NFT and I keep getting the error:

`Error HH100: Network ropsten doesn't exist`

The command I'm using can be found at step 16:

`npx hardhat --network ropsten run scripts/deploy.js`

---

This is what my `deploy.js` file looks like:

```
async function main() {
  const MyNFT = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyNFT")

  // Start deployment, returning a promise that resolves to a contract object
  const myNFT = await MyNFT.deploy()
  await myNFT.deployed()
  console.log("Contract deployed to address:", myNFT.address)
}
```

And this is what my `hardhat.config.js` file looks like:

```
/**
* @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
*/
require('dotenv').config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
module.exports = {
   solidity: "0.8.1",
   defaultNetwork: "rinkeby",
   networks: {
      hardhat: {},
      rinkeby: {
         url: API_URL,
         accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`]
      }
   },
}
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This hardhat error happens when you are trying to interact with a network that is not defined in the config file.

Specifically, because you are using the `--network ropsten` flag, the config file expects `networks.ropsten` to be defined. However, you only have `networks.rinkeby` defined. I'd recommend adding a definition for `networks.ropsten` (and making sure to use the appropriate `API_URL` for ropsten). For example:

```
/**
* @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
*/
require('dotenv').config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
const { RINKEBY_API_URL, ROPSTEN_API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
module.exports = {
   solidity: "0.8.1",
   defaultNetwork: "rinkeby",
   networks: {
      hardhat: {},
      rinkeby: {
         url: RINKEBY_API_URL,
         accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`]
      },
      ropsten: {
         url: ROPSTEN_API_URL,
         accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`]
      },
   },
}
```

With this config, if you run:

`npx hardhat --network ropsten run scripts/deploy.js`

it should work!

P.S. Also make sure you have testnet ether:

- https://www.rinkebyfaucet.com/
- https://goerlifaucet.com/
- https://faucet.dimensions.network/

Comment: Had network defined instead of networks! Thanks for the fix :)

Comment: those typos can be annoying in hardhat configs :) happy to help!